# c# for Count to maximum array.Length?

Tags: c#, arrays

Can u help a fellow noob programmer.
I will write the code first:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int m = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int[] a = new int[m];

    for (int i = 1; i < m; i++)
    {
        a[i] = i * 5;
        Console.WriteLine(a[i]);
    }
}
```

So the output here after i write 2 in input is: "5,10"
What do I add for output to be: "5 ,10, 15" (without writing 3 in input)

Comment: In the code you are showing, if you input `2`, the output is only `5`. Can you re-phrase your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your for loop needs to start at 0.  Arrays (like most collections) use 0-based indexing.

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    a[i] = (i + 1) * 5;
    Console.WriteLine(a[i]);
}
```

Comment: Agreed, but you probably want to make the array value `a[i] = (i + 1) * 5`, otherwise it will be "0, 5" instead of "5, 10".